# Can I style the event's container cell instead of the event with the fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

One of the custom properties of my events is `TypeId`.

What I'd like to do is show the entire container cells in different colors depending on what the `TypeId` of the event is. For instance, I'd like all cells that contain an event of `TypeId = 1` to have a background color of blue, and all cells that contain an event of `TypeId = 2` to have a background color of green.

I know you can change the cell's styles in the `dayRender` callback, but can I access the event that is associated with each cell at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue. 
You can get cell of event container in eventRender callback - something like this:

```js
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    var cell = view.dateToCell(event.start);
    var eventContainer = view.element.find('tr:eq(' + (cell.row + 1) + ') td:eq(' + cell.col + ')');

     //or if you similar
    var dateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    var eventContainer = view.element.find('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateString + '"]');

     eventContainer.css('background-color', 'red');




  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) which gives you access to both the event and the element (and  the view, if you need that)

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    if (event.TypeId === 1) {
        $(element).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that, but that only styles the div that contains the event. Since the title of the events vary in length, the divs that contain the events end up being different sizes, and my calendar looks rather sloppy. I'm trying to get it so that when an event is tied to a certain day, the whole day cell of the calendar gets the style.

Comment: Could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to illustrate what you have and what you want?